# Matplotlib and LaTeX: Consistent default font in specified vs. non-specified axis ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I am using Python 2.7, Matplotlib 1.5.1, and attempting to use LaTeX for all text rendering. I am trying to make the font of Plot 1's axis tick labels match those in Plot 2. For some reason, since I did not explicitly set the tick labels in Plot 1, they remain in the default LaTeX font. I would like all tick labels, regardless of whether they were explicitly set, to match the font of those in Plot 2. While knowing how to change both sets of tick label fonts to some 3rd, consistent font would be useful, I am more interested in knowing how to set Plot 1's tick fonts to be the exact font shown in Plot 2 below.

Also, since I imagine it might be a more common query from someone in the same situation, it would be good to know how to set both sets of tick labels to match those in Plot 1.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)

my_fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))

x = range(10)
y = range(10)

ax1 = my_fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax1.set_title('Plot 1')

ax2 = my_fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)
ax2.plot(x, y)
ax2.set_xticklabels(range(10))
ax2.set_yticklabels(range(10))
ax2.set_title(r'\textit{Plot 2}')
```

[image]

Comment: Ignore my (now deleted) comments, have this sorted.

Answer (score 1):

First, using `set_yticklabels` like this is dangerous because the locator is still the auto locator (automatically places ticks based on data range) but the labels come from a `FixedFormatter` which means the first tick is always labeled with the first position in the sequence which **decouples** your tick labels from your data.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)

my_fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))

x = range(10)
y = range(10)

ax1 = my_fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax1.set_title('Plot 1')

ax2 = my_fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)
ax2.plot(x, y)
# just being very explicit about what `set_xticks` and `set_xticklabels`
# is doing
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.FixedLocator(range(10)))
ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.FixedLocator(range(10)))
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker.FixedFormatter(range(10)))
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker.FixedFormatter(
    ['${}$'.format(_) for _ in range(10)]))

ax2.set_title(r'\textit{Plot 2}')
```

[image: example output]

Compare:

```
In [157]: ax2.xaxis.get_ticklabels()[1]
Out[157]: Text(1,0,'$1$')

In [158]: ax2.yaxis.get_ticklabels()[1]
Out[158]: Text(0,1,'1')

In [159]: ax1.yaxis.get_ticklabels()[1]
Out[159]: Text(0,0,'$0$')
```

In the case of the the right xaxis and both axes on the left, the numbers are typeset in math mode.  In the case on the left, the LaTeX markup is added by the `ScalarFormatter` (the default formatter).  If you used a `FixedFormatter` (which I did explicitly here, the OP code is doing implicitly via `sex_xticklabels`) no additional markup is added and the contents of the list of labels is just passed through to the `Text` instance which is used to draw the tick labels.

TL;DR

- unless you want to typeset *text* do not use `set_xticklabels`, use `set_xticks` and let the default `Formatter` 'do the right thing'
- do the LaTeX markup your self

Comment: How would I set the font of the y-axis tick labels in your Plot 1 to be the same as the font of the y-axis tick labels in your Plot 2 without specifying the actual ticks and labels? I want matplotlib to auto-generate the ticks and tick labels in Plot 1, but for them to be rendered in the font currently used for the y-axis labels in your Plot 2. That way, when I mix subplots that I have specified tick labels with ones that were auto-generated, the fonts will match (and I prefer the font of the current y-axis in Plot 2). Thanks!